# example for showing function source code

Tags: r

For an R tutorial I want to show how easy it is to see the source code of a function by just typing the name in the console / pressing F2 in Rstudio.
**I'm looking for a function that is**

```
- written in R (not using .Call, .External, .Internal etc)
- simple (not calling UseMethod)
- short
- common (in base/stats/graphics etc)
- useful
```

I'm currently thinking of `rug`, but that already has quite some if-else levels. Any nicer ideas?

```
plot(density(faithful$eruptions))
rug(density(faithful$eruptions))
rug
```

(Of course I'll in a second step reference to https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/graphics/R/rug.R and e.g. [How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function))

Comment: How about `ncol`?

Comment: nice idea. Good example to then spiral down towards .Primitive("dim")

Comment: This question will be probably be closed. But looking at specific methods for certain generic functions could be useful.  For example `head.matrix` is short and easy to understand.